# Why can not directly multiply (0.0,0.0,1.0) but have to use o.normal =float3(0.0,0.0,1.0)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

It is a part of shader in Unity3D.

I use the normal map filled with color(128,128,255) so it represent (0.0,0.0,1.0).

I doubt why this is OK?

```
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
    {
        float3 normals = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_NormalMap, IN.uv_NormalMap));
        o.Normal = float3(0.0,0.0,1.0); 

        float2 litSphereUV;
        litSphereUV.x = dot(IN.tan1, o.Normal);
        litSphereUV.y = dot(IN.tan2, o.Normal);

        half4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, litSphereUV*0.5+0.5);
        o.Albedo = c.rgb * _MainTint;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
```

And this is wrong?

```
litSphereUV.x = dot(IN.tan1, (0.0,0.0,1.0));
litSphereUV.y = dot(IN.tan2, (0.0,0.0,1.0));
```

Comment: @anderas It works! Thank you very much! But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `(0.0,0.0,1.0)` is just a list of `float`s. The `dot` function takes two `floatN`vectors as an argument, where `1<=N<=4` (IIRC). In your case, you have to construct a `float3` object to pass to the `dot`function.

Try using it like this instead:

```
litSphereUV.x = dot(IN.tan1, float3(0.0,0.0,1.0));
litSphereUV.y = dot(IN.tan2, float3(0.0,0.0,1.0));
```

This way, you construct 2 objects of type `float3` with the respective values as constructor arguments. Then, the appropriate version of the `dot` function is selected and you get the result you desired.